# Best phone plan (ideas) for travelling in France from the United States

Tags: usa, france, cellphones, data-plans

Excuse the specific nature of this question.  Hopefully it somewhat applies to a more general audience.

I live in the United States and I'm travelling to France this summer for 2 months.  I use to have a very reasonable international plan with T-Mobile: free text and data (slow! 2G) and 10 cents/minute for phone calls.  Now I'm with AT&T and the plan is not so great: $10/day or $100/month.

What options do I have for using my phone in France?  I will be near wifi a fair bit and can use that, but I want the option to use Google maps while driving and to make texts and occasionally make calls (call a restaurant/museum/etc.).  I just signed up for AT&T and got "free" phones. They are NOT unlocked.  I believe they have eSim cards.  I.e. no sim card to swap out.  Could I buy a burner phone in France? How much? Where? Could I get something set up before I leave the U.S. If I find an old phone around my house that has a physical SIM card would that be of use?

Perhaps the $100 / month will be the best I can do, but I thought I'd check with the experts.

UPDATE:  I should add that I'm most interested in making calls within France, and texts within France, and internet within France.  For calling back to the United States I can wait until I'm in an area with internet and then use WhatsApp or similar.

Thanks!

Comment: I know that sounds like a stupid answer but it worked for us: switch back to T-Mobile. We spent about 25% of our time in all sort of countries and the combo of slow-but-workable data/text + WIFI worked fine without the need of local SIM cards and huge international fees. Added bonus: it works as soon as you hit the tarmac and your caught  up on email and messages by the time you have reached the gate.

Comment: Google Maps has an offline maps function that doesn't require Internet once you've downloaded the region you're interested in.

Comment: @BenWatson doesn’t take into account current traffic conditions when offline though, but indeed very useful.